# Text Disappearing When Using Background Image Slideshow

Tags: html, css, background-image

Okay, there probably is a question out there like this, but I couldn't find anything on the first 10 pages of Google. So, I'm creating a background slideshow for my website, and I have 6 images in the slideshow.

My problem is that I can't stop my text from disappearing when each transition is made. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<ul class="bg-slideshow">
<li>
    <span>Image 1</span>
    <div> 
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Image 2</span>
    <div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Image 3</span>
    <div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Image 4</span>
    <div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Image 5</span>
    <div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Image 6</span>
    <div>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.bg-slideshow,
.bg-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.bg-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}

.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url("image2.png") 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url("image2.png");
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url("image3.png");
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url("image4.png");
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url("image5.png");
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url("image6.png");
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}

.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.bg-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}

.bg-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 0 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 0 }
    17% { opacity: 0 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.no-cssanimations .bg-slideshow li span {
    opacity: 1;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .bg-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .bg-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
8% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
17% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
}
25% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
}
100% { 
    opacity: 0
}

@keyframes titleAnimation { 
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(200px);
}
8% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
17% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
19% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-400px);
}
25% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

What am I missing? I've gone over this again and again. (And again.) Thanks!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLoh0jee/)

[image: Picture Of Problem]

Comment: Can you put it on jsfiddle ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I see what the issue is - should the spans with image x in them not rotate/disappear with the image?

Comment: @will What I mean is  I _don't_ want the text on my webpage to disappear while the slideshow is being played. Edit: Crap... I should really add the text so you can see what the problem is....

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you mean - I put together a codepen using the code you provided, what you're having an issue with is the text that says image1, image2, image3 etc disappearing? http://codepen.io/will0220/pen/kXobLP

Comment: No. I, being an idiot, didn't add the text that was disappearing. Wow. Editing it now.

Comment: @will Check out the Fiddle!

Comment: OK, I think it's pretty obvious with that update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add positioning/a z-index to the containers you want to appear over your slideshow, like so:

```
.welcome, .category_1, .category_2, .category_3{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/will0220/21f7ecf3/

Comment: This is the correct answer for this specific question, it does what I want it to (that's why it's marked as the correct answer),  except for it does this: [https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=1c55114436&view=att&th=155c208f29e4788b&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=f_iqbdkdv00&zw]. Note: Clicking that link will download an image of what I'm talking about. Thanks!

Comment: The link is tied to your inbox - I can't open it :(

Comment: It looks like you're using something to generate dropdowns like top games? You'll just want to find whatever the top-most level element of that dropdown is, then set z-index: 2 on whatever that is. Unfortunately I can't tell you which element you need without seeing it in action.